# for loop of swift 3.0 index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] error

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

before swift2.0 this is i use for forloop statement and im not getting error but when upgrading to swift3.0  the app always crash see below the one i use for forloop statement:

```
   for (var i=0; i < results.count; i++)
                {
                    let single_result = results[i]
                    let id = single_result.valueForKey("id") as! String
                    let name = single_result.valueForKey("name") as! String
                    let address = single_result.valueForKey("address") as! String
                    let mobile = single_result.valueForKey("mobile_number") as! String
                    let email = single_result.valueForKey("email") as! String
                    let gender = single_result.valueForKey("gender") as! String
                    let birth  = single_result.valueForKey("birthday") as! String
                    user_id = id
                    gotID = id
                    gotName = name
                    gotAddress = address
                    gotEmail  = email
                    gotGender = gender
                    gotMobile = mobile
                    gotBirth = birth
                }
```

Im having error when i use this loop statement(swift3.0):

```
  for i in 0.stride(through: results.count, by: 1)
  for i in 0..<results.count
```

Comment: what error are you having?

Comment: -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the [index-off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Replace

```
 for i in 0.stride(through: results.count, by: 1)
```

with

```
 for i in 0.stride(through: results.count - 1, by: 1)
```

Note the `- 1`.

Comment: This answer fixes your issue, but @nhgrif is correct in that using a for in loop would be better way to approach the problem if you are just trying to iterate through a list of results. I suggest trying it out and implementing it rather than a for loop as an index

Comment: Might be a good idea just in case anyone comes along this later and sees it. Might inspire them to use the for in as well haha. Also your answer isn't incorrect! It solved his problem for sure, I just like to encourage people to use best practices when possible :)

Comment: It's not really particularly appropriate to edit your answer to incorporate other answers from the site.  The accepted checkmark doesn't really mean *that* much and in time the upvotes will make it clear which solution to use.

Comment: In Swift, the off-by-one error is largely avoided simply by not accessing array indices directly.  The occasions for which you need to do this in a language with `for`-`in` loops are really quite rare.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to be iterating over integers when what you actually want are the values in the array.

Use a `for`-`in` loop:

```
for result in results {
    // do something with result
}
```

Using `for i in 0..<someArray.count` is pretty much always going to be a code smell.  You're going to find that you rarely need the index and the above `for`-`in` loop pattern will work in almost all circumstances.

In the rare case that you want to iterate over an array and you *do* need the index in addition to the value, you can call `enumerate` on the `array` to generate a sequence of `index`/`value` pairs:

```
for (index, result) in results.enumerate() {
    // do something with result, which is the value at results[index]
}
```